# Android Unable to cancel Vibration via VIBRATOR_SERVICE cancel()

Tags: android, vibration

Info: Android
Compiled SDK 33
Device: Pixel 6

Issue: I am having trouble using the VIBRATOR_SERVICE. All I would like to do is cancel and active vibration while its running, and start a new vibrate command (with a different intensity/duration)

Examples:

1. As you would expect, this code vibrates my device for 1 second:

```
// create vibrator instance
Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
    .build();

// vibrate for 20 seconds (unless cancelled)
vib.vibrate(20000, audioAttributes);

// wait 1 second and then cancel the vibrator
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Log.e("TAG", "Cancel Vibration");
        vib.cancel();
    }
}, 1000);
```

2. Now here is the issue. This code vibrates my device for 20 seconds. Why doesn't this vibrate the device for 1 second?

```
// create vibrator instance
Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
    .build();

// vibrate for 20 seconds (unless cancelled)
vib.vibrate(20000, audioAttributes);

// ============== NEW CODE HERE ================
vib.cancel(); // cancel the active vibration at any point
vib.vibrate(20000, audioAttributes); // start a new vibrate command
// =============== END NEW CODE ================

// wait 1 second and then cancel the vibrator
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Log.e("TAG", "Cancel Vibration");
        vib.cancel();
    }
}, 1000);
```

What am I missing here? What is the correct way to cancel the active vibration and start a new one? The first time I cancel it, I appear to lose the ability to cancel any future vibrate commands. Hoping this is something simple that I am missing, thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you found a solution/workaround for this? I am having the same issue on a TicWatch 5 pro Wear OS watch, which is based on plain Android 11 (SDK 30).

Answer (score 0):

```
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
// Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    v.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(500, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
} else {
    //deprecated in API 26 
    v.vibrate(500);
}

v.cancel();//For stop vibrator
```

Comment: It make no difference if I use vibrate()or createOneShot(). Both produce the same results. Your above example is essentially my example #1 above. Can you please update your example addressing #2 above? ie I would like to (1) vibrate then cancel it (2) vibrate then cancel a second time. No matter what, the 2nd time I cancel it, the vibration never actually stops.

Comment: Hmm actually this may be a device specific issue. On a Google Pixel 6 (Android12), #2 above doesn't cancel the vibration. On a Galaxy A32 (Android11) and LGG8(Android 10) it does.